# Wordpress RSS feeds: Customizing the feeds for specific categories

Tags: php, wordpress, rss

I have two feeds, one for articles and one for news entries. I've written a function that includes the thumbnail in the feeds. In that function I choose which thumb size to show.

The problem is that for the news feed, I want one image size, and another image size for the article feed.

Is there anyway to modify the add_filter hook to only apply the function to one category? And then maybe duplicate the function, change the thumb size and the category?

Function:

```
    function insertThumbnailRSS($content) {
global $post;
if ( has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) ){
$content = '' . get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'thumbnail' ) . '' . $content;
}
return $content;
}

add_filter('the_excerpt_rss', 'insertThumbnailRSS');
add_filter('the_content_feed', 'insertThumbnailRSS');
```

Tyty!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps try:

```
function insertThumbnailRSS($content) {
global $post;
if ( has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) && in_category(4, $post-ID) ){
    $content = '' . get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'thumbnail' ) . '' . $content;
}

if ( has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) && in_category(5, $post-ID) ){
    $content = '' . get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'different-size' ) . '' . $content;
}

return $content;
}

add_filter('the_excerpt_rss', 'insertThumbnailRSS');
add_filter('the_content_feed', 'insertThumbnailRSS');
```

Take a look at the [codex page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/in_category) for in_category().